# switch mail delivery method in rails during runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, interceptor

I'm trying to setup a rails application so that I can choose between different mail delivery methods depending on whether some condition is true or not.

So, given two delivery methods:

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :foo
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :bar
```

I thought I'd be able to just create an email interceptor to do something like this:

```
class DeliveryMethodChooser
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    if some_condition
      # code to use mail delivery method foo
    else
      # code to use mail delivery method bar
    end
  end
end
```

The problem though, is that I'm not sure how to actually set change what mail delivery method is used for a given message. Any ideas? Is it even possible to dynamically choose what delivery_method to use?

Comment: what are the two delivery methods you want?

Comment: I don't really see how that's relevant to the question, but one of them is :smtp via sendgrid and the other one will be using Amazon SES (with mailchimp STS).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, it turns out that you can actually pass a `Proc` as a default parameter to `ActionMailer`.

It's therefore fully possible to do this:

```
class SomeMailer < ActiveMailer::Base
  default :delivery_method => Proc.new { some_condition ? :foo : :bar }
end
```

I'm not sure I really sure I like this solution, but it works for the time being and it will only be for a relatively short amount of time.

Answer (score 18):

You can pass a :delivery_method option to the mail method as well:

```
def notification
  mail(:from => 'from@example.com',           
       :to => 'to@example.com', 
       :subject => 'Subject',
       :delivery_method => some_condition ? :foo : :bar)
end
```

Comment: Yes, of course you can do this, since you can set a default delivery method using the `default` method, which I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a separate ActionMailer subclass and change the delivery_method + smtp_settings like this:

```
class BulkMailer < ActionMailer::Base  
  self.delivery_method = Rails.env.production? ? :smtp : :test
  self.smtp_settings = {
    address:   ENV['OTHER_SMTP_SERVER'],
    port:      ENV['OTHER_SMTP_PORT'],
    user_name: ENV['OTHER_SMTP_LOGIN'],
    password:  ENV['OTHER_SMTP_PASSWORD']
  }

  # Emails below will use the delivery_method and smtp_settings defined above instead of the defaults in production.rb

  def some_email user_id
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Hello #{@user.name}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can also open up the application's configuration to dynamically change the delivery method application-wide:

```
SomeRailsApplication::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file
end
```

This can be useful in `db/seeds.rb` if you send account confirmation emails upon account creation, for example.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually change the method used, though.  It'll report the new method via Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method - but then still use the old one (at least for me)